# Getting this error while uploading game apk because of the app signature is different from that of the released version in AppGallery

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, android-keystore, appgallery, appgallery-connect

I am trying to upload new apk with a keystore file and its giving this errors due to app signature is different from that of the released version. Please any one help me how to get the keystore file from the store which I have used for the previous release. Is there any possibility?

Answer (score 2):

You are recommended to create the new keystore. Modified keystore will not be approved during the app review process thus no modification is recommended.

However, if you really need to make the modification, you can leave a note saying Agree to ignore keystore difference in the Notes column of the Version information page when you submit the app for review.

[image: Fig]

Please kindly note that users will not be able to update version directly via the already installed one after your app is released by doing so. Instead, users are required to uninstall the old version and reinstall the app to get the update done.